# The text and icon should change the color on hover at the same time

Tags: html, css, hover, href, font-awesome

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. The button should be connected to the link;
2. Both, the text and the icon should hover in gold at the same time (now they change the color separately, i.e. if you hover over the icon, this is not applied to the text and vice versa).
3. The icon should have larger font-size than the text.

Here is the link to my HTML and CSS: http://www.cssdesk.com/pkVpY

Thanks so much!

```
<div>
<i class="fa fa-file-text-o events_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<a class="events_btn" href="http://www.google.org/" 
target="_blank" 
style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">
VIEW ALL EVENTS
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you should state the problem you're encountering!

Comment: I did!
Both, the text and the icon should hover in gold at the same time (now they change the color separately, i.e. if you hover over the icon, this is not applied to the text and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Change the Html like this, so that the icon and text are all clickable. The way you have it now, the text is clickable, but folks cannot click the icon.

The layout should be like this:

```
<a class="some-class">
    <i></i> <!-- the icon -->
    <span></span> <!-- the text -->
</a>
```

Now keep in mind that `<div>` is `display:block` by default. `<a>` is `display: inline` by default. You will need a CSS rule on the `<a>` to make it `display:block`.

You can use direct child selector to affect all the children.

Instead of `.events_icon:hover {}`

Use `.some-class:hover>i{}`

For the text use `.some-class:hover>span{}`

Comment: It's not entirely true, the <i> tag is what will be used to an italic style to text, which is it's content will acts as text and not an icon or image. so the span in this case is unnecessary. as long as the hover styles is on the anchor tags "some-class"

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much, George!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to **hover on a div** containing **two directs elements** ( icon + text ) and that hover has the effect of **colouring those items** within and with a specific **color**:
The selectors:

- ***.text-iconed*** – your div containing the elements
- ***:hover***       – pseudoclass with hover effect
- ***>***            – this chevron is selecting the direct elements ( same level ) under the current element ( == .text-iconed div )
- *****           – all == selecting all elements
  Meaning:

> *"on this .text-iconed div hovered, take all direct children and color them"*

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class = "text-iconed">

    <i></i>
    <a>VIEW ALL EVENTS</a>

</div>



// CSS
.text-iconed:hover > * {
   color: gold   //color property is applied to svg too.
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Add your icon element inside the anchor tag.

Comment: 8 words is usually too short for a good SO answer. The codepen helps but it is better to include relevant code in the post here.

Comment: You are right, I should have been more specific in my answer.
In my defense I recently started to bring solutions to SO, so I am still learning :)

Comment: when hover icon than work but hover on text than icon color not change